# request nodejs gets unreadable data

Tags: node.js, utf-8, request, scrape

I'm trying to scrape the html using library request on node.js. The response code is 200 and the data I get is unreadable. Here my code:

```
var request = require("request");

const options = {
  uri: 'https://www.wikipedia.org',
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "text/html,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3", 
    "charset": "utf-8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/78.0.3904.108 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    }
};


request(options, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);

});
```

As you can see, I sent the request for html and utf-8 but got a large string like f��j���+���x��,�G�Y�l

My node version is v8.10.0 and the request version is 2.88.0.

Is something wrong with the code or I'am missing something??

Any hint to overtake this problem would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**

In response to your latest post:

The reason it is not working for Amazon is because the response is `gzip`ped.. In order to decompress the `gzip` response, you simply need to add `gzip: true` to the `options` object you are using. This will work for both Amazon and Wikipedia:

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
    uri: "https://www.amazon.com",
    gzip: true
}

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw error;

    console.log(body);
});
```

Lastly, if you are wanting to scrape webpages like this, it is probably best to use a web scraping framework, like [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), since it is built for web scraping.

See [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/) for `Puppeteer` GitHub.

---

---

**Original Answer:**

Since you are just grabbing the HTML from the main page, you do not have to specify `charset`, `encoding`, or `Accept-Encoding`..

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
    uri: 'https://www.wikipedia.org',
    //encoding: 'utf-8',
    headers: {
        "Accept": "text/html,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
        //"charset": "utf-8",
        //"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/78.0.3904.108 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw error

    console.log(body);
});
```

To take it a bit further... *in this scenario*, you don't need to specify headers at all...

```
const request = require('request');

request('https://www.wikipedia.org', function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw error

    console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you the reply, when I used that to the Wikipedia page works properly, but when I use it to **scrape** another website like the amazon, got the same bad result

```
const request = require('request');

request('https://www.amazon.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw error

    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution to this. Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: not working for me, same result: 
     �N_��#������>�V ZLT�Յ�"����U����������&|�1&>>^Hs)�a]]�Q�V�Vn�in���������.�e�FN!Φ���ف�y9�FF�F�A�.

Comment: And you're using this `options` object? `const options = {
    uri: "https://www.amazon.com",
    gzip: true
}` - this is an online `Node.js` environment.. it works just fine here, as well as on my machine.. https://repl.it/repls/RelevantStrictGigabyte

Comment: Thanks you, The code in the link works properly in the link but not in my computer. That makes me think that the problem is my computer. I ran the code again in my other computer with centos 7 (the first one run ubuntu 18.04) and it worked, that means that there is something wrong with the versions or the installation. I'm going to reinstall all to see if it fix that. Thanks a lot for your help.